# Creating trill staff in lilypond

Tags: piano, lilypond, trills

I'm learning BWV775 (Bach Invention IV - D Minor) and the score I'm working from has a small extra staff for a trill in measure 17

[image]

The treble & bass staves are easy enough in Lilypond, and for the trill mark, I've just used /trill in the treble voice

```
f-1[ g] g8.[ \trill f16]
```

which gives me

[image]

What's the best approach to add a staff at this measure? Create some sort of new staff with `\context Staff` in the voice at that point?

My piano scores have been pretty simple to date using

```
\score {
    \context GrandStaff <<
     \context Staff = "one" <<
       \voiceone
     >>
     \context Staff = "two" <<
       \voicetwo
     >>
   >>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation calls this an "Ossia staff" (see [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/modifying-single-staves#ossia-staves)).

The main idea is to make a new staff `\with` an `alignAboveContext` that links it to the upper staff.

- In the example in the documentation they use `firstClef = ##f` to hide the clef symbol in this new staff, but this isn't done in the image you are trying to replicate.
- To hide the time signature use:  `\remove "Time_signature_engraver"`.
- To scale the new staff use:  `\magnifyStaff #2/3`
  This will also make the bar lines thinner, so you’ll want to revert them to their usual thickness by using:
  `\revert BarLine.hair-thickness`
  `\revert BarLine.thick-thickness`
  which prevents a misalignments issue with the normal bar lines.
- You might also want to reduce the distance to the ossia staff with:
  `\override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-staff-spacing.minimum-distance = 2`
  `\override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-staff-spacing.basic-distance = 8`
- To get the lower mordent symbol use `\prall` rather than `trill`.

You should get something like this:

```
%% GRAND STAFF
\new GrandStaff {
    <<
        %% UPPER STAFF
        \new Staff = "upper" {
            \key f \major
            \time 3/8
            f'16[ g']
            <<
                {
                    g'8.[\prall f'16] |
                }
                %% OSSIA
                \new Staff \with {
                    alignAboveContext = "upper"
                    %firstClef = ##f
                    \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
                    \magnifyStaff #2/3
                    \revert BarLine.hair-thickness
                    \revert BarLine.thick-thickness
                    \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-staff-spacing.minimum-distance = 5
                    \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-staff-spacing.basic-distance = 8
                } {
                    \key f \major
                    \tuplet 3/2 {a'32 g' a'} g'8 f'16 |
                }
            >>
            f'8
        }
        %% LOWER STAFF
        \new Staff = "lower" {
            \clef "bass"
            \key f \major
            \time 3/8
            d16 bes, c8 c, |
            f,16 g,
        }
    >>
}
```

[image: Ossia staff]

Comment: I can confirm that the trill is also added to the midi output!